# Annotation selector plugging error " n.reduce is not a function "

Tags: javascript, annotations, annotorious

I'm trying to use the [slector](https://github.com/annotorious/annotorious-v2-selector-pack) plugging with another plugging [toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com)  , the problem is when I select the rectangle or poly it work good , I draw it and then I can see the widget to confirm , but when I select the circle or the eclipse , I can't even see the widget if it the widget modified or if the formatter also modified and I got in the console this error :

```
`Uncaught TypeError: n.reduce is not a function
    at _e (selector.js:1945:23)
    at new u (selector.js:2373:15)
    at a.createEditableShape (selector.js:2557:24)
    at AnnotationLayer.js:436:48
    at kS.emit (index.js:36:20)
    at ToolsRegistry.js:57:46
    at a.emit (selector.js:94:25)
    at selector.js:2552:23
    at i.mouseUp (selector.js:835:29)`
```

I thought there is a problem with my own formatter and my own widget , so I used a formatter from another plugin [ShapeLapel](https://github.com/annotorious/annotorious-v2-plugins/tree/main/plugins/annotorious-shape-labels) , but still the same problem,
here is the code :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Annotorious first -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@recogito/annotorious@latest/dist/annotorious.min.css">
    
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="my-toolbar-container"></div>
    <img id="hallstatt" src="640px-Hallstatt.jpg">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@recogito/annotorious@latest/dist/annotorious.min.js"></script>
    <script src="annotorious-shape-labels.min.js"></script> 
    <!-- Selector Pack plugin -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@recogito/annotorious-toolbar@latest/dist/annotorious-toolbar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@recogito/annotorious-selector-pack@latest/dist/annotorious-selector-pack.min.js"></script>
    <script>

      window.onload = function() {
        // Init Annotorious
       

      var anno = Annotorious.init({
          image: 'hallstatt',
          formatter: Annotorious.ShapeLabelsFormatter()
      });
         
        // Init the plugin
        Annotorious.SelectorPack(anno);
        Annotorious.Toolbar(anno, document.getElementById('my-toolbar-container'));
        // [ 'rect', 'polygon', 'point', 'circle', 'ellipse', 'freehand' ]
        console.log(anno.listDrawingTools());

      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have answered this over the Gitter support channel already. But for posterity:

Due to a bug in the current Annotorious release, the `formatter` field currently requires an array as value. Therefore, you need to change your init code to:

```js
var anno = Annotorious.init({
  image: 'hallstatt',
  formatter: [ Annotorious.ShapeLabelsFormatter() ]
});
```